# Is there a way to "reset" the Netbeans GUI builder for a form?

Tags: netbeans

I've got a medium sized form built via the Netbeans GUI builder that has a most unfortunate issue.  If I add or remove (basically touch in any way) any component, the generated code breaks horrifically.  Spewing thousands of errors about syntax.  I've been paging through and diffing through trying to figure out what the GUI builder is breaking, but it's eluding me so far.  Is there some way I can "reset" the GUI builder to generate fresh XML based on the code?  My guess is that something is going wrong when the XML is turned into code.

Comment: I can't believe that this question isn't getting any love...

Comment: 13 days.  Seems like it would have been quicker to code the GUI by hand.

Comment: It wasn't 13 days of work.  I went and worked on a different project after posting this (I've got around a dozen major projects and 27 minor projects that I'm currently assigned to/working on, never a shortage of something different to go do if I get stuck).  I just got back to this problem mid-morning today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a whole bunch of sub panels that had been built but were not active (no code to drive them yet).  I went through, commented out all my code, then removed every single component that I didn't need (a couple panels are active and in use by our customers).  I then went back through and uncommented all my code and it's magically OK now.  No more nonsensical errors whenever a GUI component is changed.  Whatever was wrong, must have been in one of the inactive components...